# How do I extract numbers from a string?

Tags: lua

How would I extract every number from a string and put them in an array?

For example the string:
"\113\115\106\111\117\41\40\105\102\109\109\112\40\42"

Answer (score 1):

You can use `string.gmatch` like this:

```
local my_array = {}
local my_string = "\\113\\115\\106\\111\\117\\41\\40\\105\\102\\109\\109\\112\\40\\42"
print(my_string) --note how the string is \ followed by digits
for number in string.gmatch(my_string, "\\(%d+)") do
   my_array[#my_array + 1] = tonumber(number)
   print(number)
end
```

This will get you an table with all the numbers from your string.
The `\` is escaped in my example to make it equal to the string you stated.

If i misunderstood your question and the numbers you want are from the chars then you need to do

```
local my_array = {}
local my_string = "\113\115\106\111\117\41\40\105\102\109\109\112\40\42"
print(my_string) --note how the string is letters
for char in string.gmatch(my_string, ".") do
    my_array[#my_array + 1] = string.byte(char)
    print(char, my_array[#my_array])
end
```